# Upgrading NServiceBus from 4 to 5: EndpointConfig, AsA_Publisher etc

Tags: c#, .net, upgrade, nservicebus

I try to upgrade NServiceBus from 4.6.1 to 5.x 
I used nuget to update the packeges.
After changing tons of code I am stuck at this point. The code contains the following class:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher, IWantCustomInitialization
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(() => XmlConfigurator.Configure());

            Configure.Transactions.Enable();
            Configure.Serialization.Json();
            Configure.Features.Disable<Sagas>();

            Configure.With()
                .DefineEndpointName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusEndpointName"])
                .DefaultBuilder()
                .RavenSubscriptionStorage()
                .UseTransport<Msmq>()
                .UnicastBus()
                .RunHandlersUnderIncomingPrincipal(false);
        }
    }
```

AsA_Publisher does not seem to exist anymore, IWantCustomInitialization is obsolete and every line inside the Init-Method throws an error ("obsolete", "cannot access static"...)

I tried to follow that document: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgradeguides/4to5

but I am stuck at this point. Event though Configuration is mentioned there I cannot find anything that looks even a close like the class I have here. What do I have to to upgrade that class to 5.x?

(Update):
Following that document: http://aradhye.com/nservicebus-upgrade-from-v4-to-v5-part1/

`Init()` has to be removed completely and instead `Customize(BusConfiguration configuration)` has to be used? Is that the right guess?

Comment: For your configuration: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgradeguides/4to5#configure-api

Comment: I've been there. So what about "AsA_Publisher" and IWantCustomInitialization? When I just remove those, I get an error that Customize(busconfiguration) has to be implemented

Comment: This might not help, but shed a *little* light: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/the-nservicebus-host#roles-built-in-configurations

Comment: @OleAlbers What about "AsA_Publisher"? Did you find anything how to replace "AsA_Publisher" in version 5?

Comment: @Algirdas After weeks of pain we decided to roll back to V4.6. Sorry. Cannot help you there.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, IConfigureThisEndpoint.Init() is obsolete and is replaced by .Customize()